# Migration from redux to redux-toolkit made react app significantly slow

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have this react app, where i used to write redux code in an old way, i used redux and redux-thunk, but, updating this packages to newer version, i had this warning where the function that i used to create my store in the app just became deprecated, and they recommended to migrate to RTK.

But, after changing all the major stuff to this new way of writing redux, everything became slower, multiple actions are taking more time to get done, and that is impacting the UI, which feels uncomfortable.

So, i want to show you the way i'm writing my actions, my reducers, how i'm updating data and pretty much how i've done everything.

This is the store/config

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import reducers from './reducers';

export const storeConfig = configureStore({
    reducer: reducers,
    devTools: true,
});

// Types for dispatching actions and store's data itself

type AppDispatch = typeof storeConfig.dispatch;
export type reducersType = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;

// Types for custom useDispatch

export const useTypedDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

These are my reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import layout from './layoutReducer';
import pickupsNoAssign from './pickupsNoAssignReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({ layout, pickupsNoAssign });

export default reducers;
```

This is my layout reducer with his actions

```
export interface ILayoutInitialState {
    authentication?: IAuthentication;
    authorizations?: IAuthorizations;

    applicationOption?: IAppOptionsPayload;
    isLeftDrawerOpen: boolean;

    terminalSeleccionada?: string | number;
    terminalNumber?: number;

    serverError: string;
}

const initialState: ILayoutInitialState = {
    isLeftDrawerOpen: true,
    serverError: '',
};

const layoutReducer = createSlice({
    name: layout,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        selectedTerminal: (state, { payload: { id, terminal } }: PayloadAction<ISelectedTerminalPayload>) => {
            state.terminalSeleccionada = terminal;
            state.terminalNumber = id;
        },
        selectedAppOption: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<IAppOptionsPayload>) => {
            state.applicationOption = payload;
        },
        leftDrawerAction: (state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLeftDrawerOpen: !state.isLeftDrawerOpen,
            };
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        // authenticating

        builder.addCase(authenticating.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            const isThereToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

            if (!isThereToken) {
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify({ ...payload.token }));
            }

            state.authentication = payload?.token;

            state.authorizations = payload.data;

            state.applicationOption = payload.appSelected;

            state.terminalSeleccionada = `${payload?.token.terminal}-${payload?.token.abreviado}`;

            state.terminalNumber = payload?.token.terminal;
        });

        builder.addCase(authenticating.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.serverError = payload?.errorMessage!;
        });
    },
});

export const { selectedTerminal, selectedAppOption, leftDrawerAction } = layoutReducer.actions;

export default layoutReducer.reducer;
```

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import {
    ITerminales,
    IAuthenthicatingParameters,
    IAuthenthicatingPayload,
} from '../../domain/entities/redux/interfaceLayout';
import { layout } from '../../domain/helpers/types';
import { gettingPermission } from '../../infrastructure/services/api/layout/appPermissions';

// Validating authorizations

export const authenticating = createAsyncThunk<
    IAuthenthicatingPayload,
    IAuthenthicatingParameters,
    {
        rejectValue: { errorMessage: string };
    }
>(`${layout}/authenticating`, async ({ token, navigate, goTo }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const data = await gettingPermission(token);

        if (data && data.isError !== true && data.response !== null) {
            // Selecting default app option
            const optionTitle = data.response[0].permisos.aplicaciones.find(
                (single) => single.id === 'sigo-distribucion',
            )?.menus[0].nombre;

            const optionApp = data.response[0].permisos.aplicaciones.find((single) => single.id === 'sigo-distribucion')
                ? data.response[0].permisos.aplicaciones.find((single) => single.id === 'sigo-distribucion')!.menus[0]
                      .sub_menu![0].nombre
                : undefined;

            // Adding default terminal
            const addDefaultTerminal: ITerminales = { id: token.terminal, abreviatura: token.abreviado };

            data.response[0].terminales.push(addDefaultTerminal);

            navigate(goTo);

            return { token, data, appSelected: { optionTitle, optionApp } };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return rejectWithValue({ errorMessage: 'Hubo un fallo al obtener los permisos' });
});
```

I'm pretty much saving user data, and manipulating some options in the UI.

Am i updating the state with bad practices ? Am i writing my actions/api calls (with createAsyncThunk) wrong ?

What could be causing such behavior ?

Comment: Are you putting very big payloads into the state somewhere? RTK uses this diffing algorithm from immerjs to mutate state in the reducers. This is really the only thing I could think of. With these sorts of performance regressions you need to pinpoint one place/one action that has become slower (subjectively) and verify that it's actually the case. A simple way to is to do `Date.now()` before and after dispatching a problematic action and calculating the difference. And then comparing it to the non-RTK version ideally.

Comment: That seems like a good point of view to try to solve this, and yes, i can have really big payloads, but Mikal Vratchanski wrote a good answer, and it's different from your approach, besides that, thank you for comment as well

Comment: Immer doesn't use a diffing algorithm as far as I know, it simply intercepts and records all modifications directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned RTK actually adds immutability and serializability checks:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware

This is very likely the root cause of the delay, I have experience with the immutability check and it can take tens of seconds to validate some very large stores.

RTK claim that the checks are not enabled in production mode, however, if you want to disable them completely do the following (code snipped from the above link + some small modification):

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: true,
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

Comment: It works know, it actually seems faster than before, when i was using only redux and react-redux instead of RTK, thank you so much sir for this !